# Riemann sum with complete system of residues of $n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How to prove this conjecture？

> **Conjecture**  $f$ is Riemann integrable function in$[0,1]$,then
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\varphi(n)}\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\(k,n)=1}}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x
> $$

similar to Weyl's criteria？

Comment: If $f(x) = e(mx)$ with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the LHS is the Ramanujan sum $\frac{1}{\varphi(n)} c_n(m) = \frac{1}{\varphi(n)} \sum_{d \mid (m,n)} d \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$. This is bounded by $\frac{\sigma_1((m,n))}{\varphi(n)} \ll_{m,\varepsilon} n^{-1 + \varepsilon}$, and so tends to zero as $n \to \infty$ for fixed $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. So by the Weyl equidistribution criterion (or just the Weierstrass approximation theorem), the conjecture is true for each continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: By a standard approximation argument (the Portmanteau lemma), this extends to any function $f$ whose set of points of discontinuity has measure zero, which is equivalent to being Riemann integrable.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum. If $f(x) = e^{2\pi i mx}$, then
$$\sum_{\substack{k \leq n \\ (k,n) = 1}} e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n} m} = c_n(m)$$
by definition.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks！

Comment: Just use the Weierstrass approximation theorem; it’s not hard.

Comment: Without the presence of $\frac{1}{\varphi(n)}$, it is literally the definition of the Ramanujan sum. I don’t understand what you’re asking. Perhaps spend some time yourself thinking through what I’ve written.

Comment: MathOverflow is a site for research mathematicians; try MathStackExchange if you need more basic questions answered.

Comment: To put it another way, the *discrepancy* of the set $A_n=\{\,k/n|1\le k\le n,\gcd(k,n)=1\,\}$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, so the average value of any Riemann-integrable function on $A_n$ goes to its integral on $[0,1]$ as $n\to\infty$. This is probably covered in the Kuipers and Niederreiter book on uniform distribution modulo one.